# Make the <li class> to be Active when click submenu

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Currently i'm using AdminLTE template for my dashboard, but for the second drop down after i click the the second menu, that menu is not stay but it's closing.

When Cascade

[image: When Cascade]

After Click

[image: After Click]

Below is my html code. I'm using codeigniter so i use this anchor for .

```
 <?php if($this->session->userdata('usergroup') == '1' or $this->session->userdata('usergroup') ==  '4') { ?>
    <li class="treeview">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Ticketing</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><?php echo anchor('Bticketing/Ballticket',"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> All Ticket") ?></li>
         <li><?php echo anchor('Bticketingcalendar',"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Calendar") ?></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

What i want is after i click the all ticket, that menu is stay and show the page. how to do that ?

Note : the default one for active is `<li class="treeview active">` but how to make it dynamic to all menu.

Answer (score 5):

Here is code if you want to create active state on AdminLTE menu

```
var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
}).closest('.treeview').addClass('active');
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<li class="treeview ticketing-tree">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Ticketing</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><?php echo anchor('Bticketing/Ballticket',"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> All Ticket") ?></li>
     <li><?php echo anchor('Bticketingcalendar',"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> Calendar") ?></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Add following JQuery code in your page

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr("href");
   var segment = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   if(segment == 'Ballticket'){
      $('.ticketing-tree').addClass('active');
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: i've been paste your jQuery it doesn't impact, still active on the top menu

Answer (score 0):

On reference website you can see what you are missing actually...

[image]

Here onclick of sub-menu you need to add active class

Comment: hi @kunal i don't see the active class on default template AdminLTE, and i've try to added that one also, it seems doesn't impact. can you show me the proper code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    // Will only work if string in href matches with location
    $('.treeview-menu li a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
    $('.treeview-menu li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using

```
<li class="treeview <?php if($page == 'YourPage'){echo 'active';}?>" >
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

this is work in my project.
`$page` is variable from your page displayed.